# pass event and object to function in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to react trying to implement `Redux` I'm trying to update state when a text-input gets updated. I'm able to extract the `e.target.value` but it also needs to be aware of what object was changed

For example my data might be something like:

```
{ name: 'Penny', namePlural: 'Pennies', label: '1¢', value: .01, sum: 0 },
{ name: 'Nickel', namePlural: 'Nickels', label: '5¢', value: .05, sum: 0 },
{ name: 'Dime', namePlural: 'Dimes', label: '10¢', value: .10, sum: 0 },
{ name: 'Quarter', namePlural: 'Quarters', label: '25¢', value: .25, sum: 0 }
```

I need to update the `sum` for a particular denomination.

Here is what I have for my presentation component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class DenomInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            denom: props.denom
        }
    }

    handleKeyUp = (e) => {
        this.props.onDenomChange(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="input-group denom">
                <span className="input-group-addon">{this.state.denom.label}</span>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    onChange={this.handleKeyUp}
                    value={this.state.denom.sum} />

                <span className="input-group-addon">{this.state.denom.count | 0}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

DenomInput.PropTypes = {
    denom: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default DenomInput;
```

With this I'm able to get the value of the input field, but how could I pass up which denomination I'm currently on as well?

Comment: why not passing the another value as a second parameter like this: `this.props.onDenomChange(e.target.value, this.state.denom.name);` ?

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't have access to `this.state`

Comment: you are using `arrow function` it will definitely have the access, can you tell me the error that you are getting when using `this.state` ?

Comment: do I need to add parameters to this line first? `onChange={this.handleKeyUp}`

Comment: no that is not required, simply pass the parameter in this: `this.props.onDenomChange(e.target.value, this.state.denom.name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayank's comment is correct, you can modify your `props.onDenomChange` function to accept a `denom` as the second argument. But in order for your `handleKeyUp` function to access component state, you'll need to explicitly bind the handler. So your input JSX should look like this:

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  onChange={this.handleKeyUp.bind(this)}
  value={this.state.denom.sum} />
```

Comment: Is it better to bind the event in the constructor for performance?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, the `bind` method will be called every time the component re-renders. But both work.

Comment: when I add `this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);` in constructor I get an error saying `onDenomChange` is not a function

Comment: You can add `onDenomChange` to your prop validations to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I added a follow up question here if you have a moment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168568/pass-function-down-to-child-component-in-react

Answer (score 0):

On first place, i would recommend you to avoid state at all, but if you want to keep it don't forget to update state after receiving new properties.

Assuming you want to change just sum property:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class DenomInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            denom: props.denom
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        const {denom} = nextProps;
        this.setState({denom});
    }

    handleKeyUp = (e) => {
        const {denom} = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        denom.sum = e.target.value;
        this.props.onDenomChange(denom);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="input-group denom">
                <span className="input-group-addon">{this.state.denom.label}</span>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    onChange={this.handleKeyUp}
                    value={this.state.denom.sum} />

                <span className="input-group-addon">{this.state.denom.count | 0}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

DenomInput.PropTypes = {
    denom: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default DenomInput;
```

And if you want to change several properties:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class DenomInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            denom: props.denom
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        const {denom} = nextProps;
        this.setState({denom});
    }

    handleKeyUp = (e) => {
        const {denom} = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        denom[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.props.onDenomChange(denom);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="input-group denom">
                <span className="input-group-addon">{this.state.denom.label}</span>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    onChange={this.handleKeyUp}
                    name='sum'
                    value={this.state.denom.sum} />
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    onChange={this.handleKeyUp}
                    name='value'
                    value={this.state.denom.value} />

                <span className="input-group-addon">{this.state.denom.count | 0}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

DenomInput.PropTypes = {
    denom: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default DenomInput;
```