# Pass function down to child Component in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to pass a function down to a child component in React. If I place the function within the ES6 class I have access to `this.props.dispatch`, but do not have access within `mapStateToProps`

Conversely when I define the function outside of the ES6 class I seem to have access to the function but not `this.props.dispatch`

Can someone identify what I am doing wrong to have both access to `this.props.dispatch` as well as having the function available in `mapStateToProps` function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import DenomInput from '../denomInput/DenomInput.js';
import * as actions from '../../actions/countActions';

class CountableItems extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onDenomChange = this.onDenomChange.bind(this);
  }

  onDenomChange = (value, denom) => {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.increaseSum(value, denom));
    console.log(value);
  }

  render() {
    const props = this.props;

    let denomGroups = props.denoms.map(function (denom, i) {
      return (
        Object.keys(denom).map(function (key) {
          let denoms = denom[key].map(function (item, i) {
            return <DenomInput denom={item} onDenomChange={props.onDenomChange} key={i}></DenomInput>
          });
          return (<div className="col"><h2>{key}</h2>{denoms}</div>)
        })
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="countable-item-wrapper">
        <div className="row">
          {denomGroups}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    denoms: state.count.denomGroups,
    onDenomChange: this.onDenomChange
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CountableItems);
```

Here is the component that renders `<CountableItems>`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CountableItems from '../components/countableItems/CountableItems.js';
import CountSummary from '../components/countSummary/CountSummary.js';

import "./Count.css";

class Count extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-8">
            <CountableItems />
          </div>
          <div className="col-4">
            <CountSummary />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Count;

Comment: No `onDenomChange` prop is present where you are constructing the `<CountableItems />`; it isn't being passed any props. Where were you expecting the function to come from?

Comment: Do you just want to call the instance's `onDenomChange` method?

Comment: Essentially <DenomInput> needs to be able to call <CountableItems>'s onDenomChange function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass a reference to the `CountableItems` instance's `onDenomChange` property. You can do that by referencing `this.onDenomChange` like `onDenomChange={this.onDenomChange}`.

Important note: you need to use arrow functions `() => {}` in order for for `this` to reference the `CountableItems` instance inside your nested loops. Regular functions like `function () {}` would not use the correct context.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import DenomInput from '../denomInput/DenomInput.js';
import * as actions from '../../actions/countActions';

class CountableItems extends Component {
  onDenomChange = (value, denom) => {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.increaseSum(value, denom));
    console.log(value);
  }

  render() {
    let denomGroups = this.props.denoms.map((denom, i) => {
      return (
        Object.keys(denom).map((key) => {
          let denoms = denom[key].map((item, i) => {
            return <DenomInput denom={item} onDenomChange={this.onDenomChange} key={i}></DenomInput>
          });
          return (<div className="col"><h2>{key}</h2>{denoms}</div>)
        })
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="countable-item-wrapper">
        <div className="row">
          {denomGroups}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    denoms: state.count.denomGroups,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CountableItems);
```